# Incorporate Wordpress authentication into php file?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wamp

I have a php file I would like to require Wordpress authentication, so you can only access the page when you're logged in. I don't want people to be able to find the file by typing in the path.

Currently I'm running WAMP and using local host. I have the file inside a "template" folder that's inside the Wordpress folder.

What would I need to add to this code to make it login protected using Wordpress?

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM category";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$output = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 $output .= '<option value="'.$row["category_id"].'">'.$row["category_name"].'</option>';
}
?>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Mankato State University - Inquriy Tools</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-bootgrid/1.3.1/jquery.bootgrid.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-bootgrid/1.3.1/jquery.bootgrid.js"></script>  
  <style>
   body
   {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color:#f1f1f1;
   }
   .box
   {
    width:1270px;
    padding:20px;
    background-color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin-top:25px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container box">
   <a href="https://www.mnsu.edu/"><h1 align="center"><img src="msu-logo-large.jpg" align="center"></h1></a>
   <br />
   <br />
   <div align="right">
    <button type="button" id="add_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#productModal" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Add</button>
     <button onclick="location.href='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-login.php?loggedout=true'" class="btn btn-info btn-lg type="button">Logout</button>
     <button onclick="location.href='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/about.php'" class="btn btn-info btn-lg type="button">Settings</button>
   </div>
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="product_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th data-column-id="FORM_ID" data-type="numeric">ID</th>
       <th data-column-id="worker_name">Worker</th>
       <th data-column-id="category_name">Category</th>
       <th data-column-id="student_name">Student</th>
       <th data-column-id="tech_id">TechID</th>
       <th data-column-id="course_wanted">Course</th>
       <th data-column-id="email">Email</th>
       <th data-column-id="phone">Phone</th>
       <th data-column-id="date">Date</th>
       <th data-column-id="comments">Comments</th>
       <th data-column-id="status">Status</th>
       <th data-column-id="commands" data-formatter="commands" data-sortable="false">Commands</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
    </table>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#add_button').click(function(){
  $('#product_form')[0].reset();
  $('.modal-title').text("Add Student");
  $('#action').val("Add");
  $('#operation').val("Add");
 });

 var productTable = $('#product_data').bootgrid({
  ajax: true,
  rowSelect: true,
  post: function()
  {
   return{
    id: "b0df282a-0d67-40e5-8558-c9e93b7befed"
   };
  },
  url: "fetch.php",
  formatters: {
   "commands": function(column, row)
   {
    return "<button type='button' class='btn btn-warning btn-xs update' data-row-id='"+row.FORM_ID+"'>Edit</button>" + 
    "&nbsp; <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs delete' data-row-id='"+row.FORM_ID+"'>Delete</button>";
   }
  }
 });

 $(document).on('submit', '#product_form', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var category_id = $('#category_id').val();
  var worker_name = $('#worker_name').val();
  var student_name = $('#student_name').val();
  var tech_id = $('#tech_id').val();
  var course_wanted = $('#course_wanted').val();
  var email = $('#email').val();
  var phone = $('#phone').val();
  var comments = $('#comments').val();
  var form_data = $(this).serialize();
  if(category_id != '' && worker_name != '' && student_name != '' && tech_id != '' && course_wanted != '' && email != '' && phone != '' && comments != '')
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"insert.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:form_data,
    success:function(data)
    {
     alert(data);
     $('#product_form')[0].reset();
     $('#productModal').modal('hide');
     $('#product_data').bootgrid('reload');
    }
   });
  }
  else
  {
   alert("All Fields are Required");
  }
 });

 $(document).on("loaded.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function()
 {
  productTable.find(".update").on("click", function(event)
  {
   var FORM_ID = $(this).data("row-id");
    $.ajax({
    url:"fetch_single.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{FORM_ID:FORM_ID},
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data)
    {
     $('#productModal').modal('show');
     $('#category_id').val(data.category_id);
     $('#worker_name').val(data.worker_name);
     $('#student_name').val(data.student_name);
     $('#tech_id').val(data.tech_id);
     $('#course_wanted').val(data.course_wanted);
     $('#email').val(data.email);
     $('#phone').val(data.phone);
     $('#comments').val(data.comments);
     $('#status').val(data.status);
     $('.modal-title').text("Edit Product");
     $('#FORM_ID').val(FORM_ID);
     $('#action').val("Edit");
     $('#operation').val("Edit");
    }
   });
  });
 });

 $(document).on("loaded.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function()
 {
  productTable.find(".delete").on("click", function(event)
  {
   if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?"))
   {
    var FORM_ID = $(this).data("row-id");
    $.ajax({
     url:"delete.php",
     method:"POST",
     data:{FORM_ID:FORM_ID},
     success:function(data)
     {
      alert(data);
      $('#product_data').bootgrid('reload');
     }
    })
   }
   else{
    return false;
   }
  });
 }); 
});
</script>
<div id="productModal" class="modal fade">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <form method="post" id="product_form">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
     <h4 class="modal-title">Add Student</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
     <label>Select Request Type</label>
     <select name="category_id" id="category_id" class="form-control" required>
      <option value="">Select Request Type</option>
      <?php echo $output; ?>
     </select>
     <br />
     <label>Enter Worker Name</label>
     <input type="text" name="worker_name" id="worker_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Worker first and last name" required/>
     <br />
     <label>Enter Student Name</label>
     <input type="text" name="student_name" id="student_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Student first and last name" required/>
     <br />
     <label>Enter TechID</label>
     <input type="number" name="tech_id" id="tech_id" class="form-control" placeholder="Tech id" required/>
     <br />
     <label>Enter Course</label>
     <input type="text" name="course_wanted" id="course_wanted" class="form-control" placeholder="Section and course id" required/>
     <br />
     <label>Enter Email</label>
     <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required/>
     <br />
     <label>Enter Phone</label>
     <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" required/>
     <br />
     <label>Enter Comment</label>
     <input type="text" name="comments" id="comments" class="form-control" placeholder="Put N/A for blank"/>
     <br />
     <label>Enter Status</label>
     <input type="text" name="status" id="status" class="form-control" placeholder="Auto added"/>
     <br />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
     <input type="hidden" name="FORM_ID" id="FORM_ID" />
     <input type="hidden" name="operation" id="operation" />
     <input type="submit" name="action" id="action" class="btn btn-success" value="Add" />
    </div>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26457/how-to-use-wordpress-authentication-on-non-wordpress-page

Comment: Doesn't work. Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this solution - [Click Here](http://dovy.io/wordpress/authenticating-outside-of-wordpress-on-diff-domain/)

Set Your Defines

```
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', false );
define( 'DISABLE_WP_CRON', true );
```

Load the WordPress Core

```
require("/var/www/yourdomain.com/htdocs/wp-load.php");
```

Verify, Authenticate, Set Cookie

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
} else {
    $creds                  = array();
    // If you're not logged in, you should display a form or something
    // Use the submited information to populate the user_login & user_password
    $creds['user_login']    = "";
    $creds['user_password'] = "";
    $creds['remember']      = true;
    $user                   = wp_signon( $creds, false );
    if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
        echo $user->get_error_message();
    } else {
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID, true );
    }
}
```

Last Check & Using the Session

```
 if ( !is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
    // Success! We're logged in! Now let's test against EDD's purchase of my "service."
    if ( edd_has_user_purchased( $user->ID, '294', NULL ) ) {
        echo "Purchased the Services and is active.";
    } else {
        echo "Not Purchased";
    }
}
```